# How do I optimize DB2 query - joining million rows with one row

Tags: sql, db2

I have a db2 query which joins a fact table (300M rows) with a date table (1 row). The dates from the date table is used on the where condition to fetch only that date's data. But the query for 3 hours.

```
Select * from fact, date 
where fact.procdate between date.lastdate and date.currdate
```

Is there a way to optimize this query without using plsql?

Comment: Start with looking at the explain plan and see where most of the time is spent.
I don't know DB2 but try to switch the order of the tables in the `select` statement. What might be happening is that the database reads each line in `fact` and then scans `date`, instead of just reading that one line in `date` and do one iteration over `fact` using an index.
Also make sure that `fact.procdate` is indexed.

Comment: Just something that comes to mind.... if you are only selecting 1 row from dates, why don't you just run two queries?  1 for the date table, and then pull the facts.  How many fields are in the two tables that your selecting * from.... a bit of a guess not knowing the table details but sounds like quite a bit of memory potentially saved.

Comment: If I use two queries in an etl tool then the fact query will bring all the records. I need the second table to filter the first

Comment: Side note: don't use `BETWEEN` - you should be using [an exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (this applies to _all_ positive, contiguous-range types, as it's an intrinsic property of how numbers are represented).  @benji - DB2, like most modern RDBMSs, will reorder tables and conditions as it sees fit to produce better plans.  That said, you it would be better to use an explicit `JOIN` (and I'd probably write it as `FROM date ...`).

Comment: I use >= and <= in the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

If you feed that query to [db2expln](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0005736.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-6-47) you will see that all 300M lines get evaluated, probably several times. You are asking DB2 to build [cartesian product](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm), and after that evaluate the where clause.

In any case, that query might not even give you the results you are expecting. You should study the output more carefully to determine that. You more likely want to do something like

```
Select * from fact 
where fact.procdate between DATE("firstdate") and DATE("seconddate")
```

The firstdate and seconddate you should supply from your application logic (probably separate queries to the table date). Alternatively you could set up subqueries to retrieve the beginning and end dates.

Comment: I tried subqueries to fetch dates. No difference in performance. The solution I currently use is retrieving the dates separately by an Unix script and feed it into informatics via mapping variable. That way I can restrict the number of fact table records in the source qualifier itself. Just raised this question to know if there is a better solution with just queries

Comment: @Amsakanna That would be something like "select * from fact where fact.procdate between (select lastdate from date where xx yy zz) and (select currdate from date where zz ii kk)", but you must NOT ... "from fact, date" in the main query as explained, without giving any where clauses that would stop producing cartesian product. Please STUDY what cartesian product means.

Comment: In the comment above, I told that I used subqueries in vain. The subqueries are fired for every row thus leading to similar intermediate result as Cartesian.